# MPAndroidChart MarkerView

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have intention on looking for a specific point in a line chart of [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and then display the the marker to highlight the point after a button is hit. The example given is where the marker is only displayed after touching event which is different in my case. I tried code below but to no avail, can some one please teach me I would appreciate.

```
Highlight h = new Highlight((int) valIndex, linechart2.getData().getDataSetCount());
        linechart2.highlightValue(h, true);
mv2.refreshContent2(valueYAxis.get((int) valIndex), h);
linechart2.getMarkerView();
linechart2.setDrawMarkerViews(true);
linechart2.getData().setHighlightEnabled(true);
//        RefreshChart();
linechart2.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily highlight values programmatically by using one of the following methods on your `Chart` object:

- `highlightValues(Highlight[] highs)`: Highlights the values at the given indices in the given DataSets. Provide null or an empty array to undo all highlighting.
- `highlightValue(int xIndex, int dataSetIndex)`: Highlights the value at the given x-index in the given DataSet. Provide -1 as the x-index or dataSetIndex to undo all highlighting.

It's all in the [**wiki**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart).

Answer (score 1):

the makerview will show when the point is highlighted, so you can try this

```
Highlight h = new Highlight((int) valIndex, 0);
mv2.refreshContent2(valueYAxis.get((int) valIndex), h);
linechart2.setMarker(mv2);
linechart2.highlightValue(h);
```